# Python XML parsing comparison of files

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have to compare two XML files using Python. Each has a list of items and I have to output which items do not appear in both. Each item has various properties which need to agree to see if it's the same item.

Which parser would be the most suitable. It has to already be included in Python 2.7. I looked at etree but does it enable me to do what I want easily? Or is there something else that would be more suitable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it depends, if your xml element have sub element, and that sub element also need to be compared, use DOM,

your elements to be compared only has attributes, thant using SAX is best way, I post some SAX code here you can ref:

```
import xml.sax
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler

class TableHandler(ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.columns = {}

    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        if name == 'R':
            for k, v in attrs.items():
                if not self.columns.has_key(k):
                    self.columns[k] = []
                self.columns[k].append(v)

def xml_to_table(xml_str):
    handler = TableHandler()
    xml.sax.parseString(xml_str, handler)
    return handler.columns

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    txt = """<xml>
    <R CatalogId="8"/><R CatalogId="8"/><R CatalogId="7"/>
    </xml>
    """

    columns = xml_to_table(txt)
    print columns
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lxml](http://lxml.de/). You can go through the items of the first file and check if they're in the second file with `xml.find(".//itemname")`